# How to query mongodb aggregation? For social media

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have a post collection and user collection, this is how it looks like...

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"612ba0ea0b5162a16c5a5ed2"},
"fullName":"chokli",
"email":"chokli@gmail.com",
"password":"$2b$10$Z.Cz6t0zqD20sECQh4O0d.KKOOJ7/oUDusbdyLveG2Jp0mvYaUP6q",
"avatar":"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/hfkalhfgkf.svg",
"posts":["6130aaf9e6251bd37caba706"],
"friendRequests":[Array],
"friends":[
        {"$oid":"612bb49619e53a326082bd0a"},
        {"$oid":"612bb4a419e53a326082bd0c"}
]}
```

each user document has an array of friends which holds the object id of the friends(another user)

also each user's posts are stored in a separate collection, this is how it looks like

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"612f6db6598edf3089ee583b"},
"postContent":"new post",
"createdAt":{"$date":"2021-09-01T12:10:30.561Z"},
"userId:{"$oid":"612bb49619e53a326082bd0a"},
"authorName":"author Name",
"avatar":"https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/human/vishnu@gmail.com.svg",
"likes":[],
"comments":[]
}
```

Im trying to retrive a user's and each of his friends posts from the posts collection..but I'm not  able to figure out how to execute the 2 lookups in the same query..

I want to do a lookup on friends post after unwinding friends array and then lookup for users post but the problem is that there are duplicate posts being fetched..

here is my query

```
db
          .getDb()
          .collection(collections.USERS)
          .aggregate([
            {
              $match: {
                _id: ObjectId(currentUserId),
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$friends",
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "posts",
                localField: "friends",
                foreignField: "userId",
                as: "friendsPosts",
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$posts",
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "posts",
                localField: "posts",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "userPost",
              },
            },
            {
              $project: {
                allPosts: {
                  $concatArrays: ["$userPost", "$friendsPosts"],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$allPosts",
            },
            {
              $sort: {
                "allPosts.createdAt": -1,
              },
            },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: "",
                allPosts: {
                  $addToSet: "$allPosts",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $project: {
                allPosts: 1,
                _id: 0,
              },
            },
          ])
          .toArray();
```

NB: this is for  SOCIAL MEDIA clone, I'm trying to show each user their home page with post from their friends and themselve in a sorted order(new posts on top) so any other suggestions on database structure as well as query will be useful

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your aggregation pipeline and it works as intended with no duplicates... It's possible in your other user documents you have the same id listed under their posts array so it is pulling down the post for you and them.

For generating pipelines like this it's vastly easier to use MongoDB Compass as you can test each stage and see what would be returned whilst you build it, then export it to your specific language as required.

As for structure a great starting place is from Mongo themselves: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: Thanks for the link... anyhow I ended up storing a copy of each user's 'posts' in the user collection as well as the 'posts' coll. under the 'posts' field that way I can use a single lookup for friends' posts. Also, it turns out lookup's localField can accept an array so that I don't have to unwind the 'friends' array